# Orbits under an algebraic group inside a Shimura variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, shimura-varieties, symmetric-spaces

Let $(G,X)$ be a Shimura datum, $K$ a compact open subgroup of $G(\mathbb A_f)$. Let $H\subset G$ be a $\mathbb Q$-subgroup. Choose a point $x\in X$. What can be said about the orbit $H(\mathbb R)\cdot x\subset X$ (or its image in $Sh_K(G,X)$) in general? When is it an hermitian symmetric domain, for example?

If $x$ corresponds to a morphism $h_x: \mathbb S\to G_\mathbb R$ which factorizes through $H_\mathbb R$ then we get a subvariety of Shimura type. If $H$ is the inverse image of $H_1$ in a decomposition $M^{ad}=H_1 \times H_2$, where $M$ is a $\mathbb Q$-subgroup of $G$ and $h_x$ factorizes through $M$, then it is a totally geodesic subvariety of $X$ (cf. Moonen "Linearity properties of Shimura varieties I").